# Heroku - Created a facebook app with Node.js which gives type error

Tags: facebook, node.js, heroku

I am trying to create a facebook application and this is my first time. I read several articles on how to create one and I created an application from this page https://developers.facebook.com/apps. When I clicked on Go to App from facebook right after I created it. It is showing this error 
[image]

I have tried to look on Heroku dev center for same type of problem to resolve problem on my own I couldn't find any solution. When I do `curl -v https://tranquil-oasis-2533.herokuapp.com`  it says HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error. This is the output from heroku logs http://pastebin.com/0qdueiZE. Somebody please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be an issue with the faceplate module. It is described here: https://github.com/heroku/faceplate/pull/20

You have two options to get around the issue:

1. Propose a fix to faceplate that works within the constraints of the Facebook application security here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ApplicationSecurity/
2. Take your Facebook app out of sandbox mode.

Comment: opting out of sandbox mode fixed this for me

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be issue with sandbox mode. Disable sandbox mode. Here is the steps how you can do it.
 Go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps.

click "Edit Settings"

and selected radio button "disabled" for the "Sanbox Mode" under "basic info".

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The error message points to what needs to be known

> Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

`<title><%= app.name %></title>`

`app` is undefined. Probably want to check your web.js file to see what `app` is up to.

And ensure you have the latest node template for Heroku.

https://github.com/heroku/facebook-template-nodejs

Comment: In web.js app is defined like  http://pastebin.com/XnQHPejh. There is no app.name in that entire file.

Comment: How should I add app.name to web.js ??

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you aren't passing `app` as a local to the index.ejs template. If you're using Express, `console.log(res.locals)` before you `res.render` index.ejs. Is `app` in the logged output?

Comment: I am sorry but I am very knew to all of this. I don't know about Express or Node.js or other things. I only know basic Javascript. Can you explain in somewhat simpler terms?